# Assigning element to variable to get .text() works, where selecting array [0] fails

Tags: jquery

Why does this work:

```
var elm = $('[action="/cart/add"]').filter(":visible").children('[name="id"]').children("option").filter(":selected")[0]
$(elm).text();
//"some option actual text"
```

And this not work:

```
$('[action="/cart/add"]').filter(":visible").children('[name="id"]').children("option").filter(":selected")[0].text();
//TypeError: Property 'text' of object #<HTMLOptionElement> is not a function
```

Is there something I can add to the end of the chain after [0] to make it work?

Comment: Why do you want to use [0]? you know what [0] does, right? (it returns the first dom node, which isn't a jquery object and therefore doesn't have a .text method) There are other methods that filter a jquery object down to a specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use `text` without parentheses (`text` is a property of an
   [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement))
2. Or, in jQuery way, you should take text like this:

   `$('[action="/cart/add"]').filter(":visible").children('[name="id"]').children("option").filter(":selected").eq(0).text();`

Here is the [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/cLSRE/)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are wrapping a non-jquery element with jquery. The [0] makes it a non-jquery element.

This slight modification to the second one would make it work:

```
$($('[action="/cart/add"]').filter(":visible").children('[name="id"]').children("option").filter(":selected")[0]).text();
```

(Notice the extra $() wrapping everything except the .text())

Answer (score 1):

The second example fails because each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, and by using `[0]` you're returning the DOM node and not a jQuery object, so you can't use `.text()`, a jQuery function, on a DOM node, only jQuery objects.

`.filter(":selected").first().text()` or `.filter(":selected").eq(0).text()` should work in place of `.filter(":selected")[0].text()`

Answer (score 1):

You should select the first element using a jquery method instead so that you can continue using jquery methods.

```
.children("option").filter(":selected").eq(0).text();
```

or

```
.children("option").filter(":selected:first").text();
```

or even

```
.children("option").filter(":selected").first().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a previous post stated by using [0] you're using the DOM node instead of a jQuery object. Here is a way to consolidate your command:

```
$('[action="/cart/add"]:visible [name="id"] option:selected:first').text()
```